# I want to get ubuntu 14.04 plugins

Tags: plugins

I installed 32 bit Ubuntu 14.04 OS for my computer. But I can't play music / videos.  When I do a double click a song / video  an error message will appear on the screen asking me to install the plugins.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. If my answer helps you, click on the "v" next to it. If it doesn't explain me why.

Comment: open software update and check for update it will recommend you plugins

Comment: What music/videos do you want to play? Have you installed the `ubutnu-restricted-extras` package?

Answer (score 0):

Install **vlc**

Enter on Ubuntu Software Center, search for VLC and install it.

After that, right click on your music/video and open with VLC

Comment: he asking for plugins not application

Comment: I agree with you. I wrote an workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

This will attempt to install all of the "restricted" packages, such as MP3 codecs. These are not natively built into Ubuntu due to licensing restrictions. An end user must manually install them.

If the above fails to work for you, open your file in the Movies program built in to your computer. It will automagically find the proper codecs and install them for you. As it seems like you've already encountered this dialog, just agree to let it install the proper plugins and everything will work as expected.